# Parameterized Runnable with function parameter

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I want to make a "generic" class which implements `Runnable` and has some parameters, including function. I started like this :

```
public static class ParameterizedTask implements Runnable {
    private String log;
    //other parameters

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do stuff with parameters
    }

    //getters and setters
```

Moreover, I want to be able to pass a specific function, which can use the other parameters. **This function will be used in `run()`.**

I thought to use `Callable`, but I can't figure out how to complete this.

My goal is having a generic `Runnable` that I can use in Android to display `AlertDialog` from inside a thread (this is why I need `Handler` and `Runnable`).

Do you have any idea ? I want to do something like that :

```
Utils.ParameterizedTask task = new Utils.ParameterizedTask();
task.setLog(...).setRandomParam(...).setFunction(<Stuff with parameters);
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(task);
```

Here, `<Stuff with parameters>` represents what `run()` should execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface called `TaskExecutor` as follows :

```
public interface TaskExecutor {
   public void execute(String log)     
}
```

You can then modify your `ParameterizedTask` class as follows :

```
public static class ParameterizedTask implements Runnable {
    private String log;
    //other parameters

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public  ParameterizedTask(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
       this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        taskExecutor.execute(log);
    }
}
```

You can then define different behavior to be executed inside the `run` method as follows :

```
ParameterizedTask task = new ParameterizedTask(new TaskExecutor() { 
        public void execute(String log) {
              //doSomething with the log
        }
   }
);
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however I would like to use the other parameters in some cases. With this solution, I need to create multiple interfaces.

I just want to pass an anonymous function which can use the class parameters, but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @Chostakovitch You don't need to create multiple interfaces. You can add more arguments to execute method and pass only those that you are interested in.

Comment: I remove my comment because I just understood. I'll accept your answer, thank you.

Comment: @Chostakovitch There is another way of solving this problem if you don't like the current approach. I will post it later in the day if possible :)

Comment: Thank you so much Chetan ! I will use your solution for the moment, it seems good to me. However I will be very happy to learn another way to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is similar to what [rxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) does with anonymous classes. In general they have generic classes like [actions and functions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/tree/1.x/src/main/java/rx/functions) and you could use this sources for your purpose.

Comment: I am used to see `Action` and `Function` in C#. Is this the same thing ?

Comment: Yes this is same concept.